# What is onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

Tags: android, android-menu

What are the two parameters Menu and menu in method `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` and how to use this method. 
I have another question why `this` parameter is used in

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
```

Comment: Menu is Class & menu is object of that class.

Comment: Intent will take the `Context` as the first parameter. In the statement `Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);`, `this` parameter represents current context of the class.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Menu is just the type of the parameter menu. For example you can have a String type for a variable named string, dog, etc. And in this case there's a Menu type for a parameter named menu.

You use onCreateOptionsMenu() to specify the options menu for an activity.
In this method, you can inflate your menu resource (defined in XML) into the Menu provided in the callback.

For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Fore more information, visit this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html).

As for [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html),

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called.

For example:

```
public void sendMessage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
}
```

The constructor takes two parameters and a Context as its first parameter.
**this** represents environment data and provides global information about an application environment.

For more information on the intent example you provided, check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) out.

Comment: I would also like to include this [link] (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)), I find the link in the answer tells you how setup onCreateOptionsMenu but doesn't do a good job describing the method.

Comment: And don't forget setHasOptionsMenu(true) on `onCreate`

Answer (score 28):

The intent of implementing this method is to populate the `menu` passed with the items you define in the `R.menu.game_menu` layout file.

#Java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

#Kotlin

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu)
    return true
}
```

After inflating the menu with the items you might want to add some action when they are selected:

## Java

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item:
            // Action goes here
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

## Kotlin

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.menu_item -> {
            // Action goes here
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## When `onCreateOptionsMenu` is called?

`onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called by the Android runtime when it need to create the option menu.

[Android Developer Guide: Menus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus)

> If you've developed your application for Android 2.3.x and lower, the system calls onCreateOptionsMenu() to create the options menu when the user opens the menu for the first time. If you've developed for Android 3.0 and higher, the system calls onCreateOptionsMenu() when starting the activity, in order to show items to the app bar.

## How to build an option menu?

Please refer to other anwsers.

## Why `onCreateOptionsMenu` return `Boolean`

[Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu))

> You must return true for the menu to be displayed; if you return false it will not be shown.

## Why `onOptionsItemSelected` return `Boolean`

> When you successfully handle a menu item, return true. If you don't handle the menu item, you should call the superclass implementation of onOptionsItemSelected() (the default implementation returns false).