# How can I change menu items in top bar in different fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I use MaterialToolBar for showing TopAppBar.
I have three fragments, when showing each of them, I want to show different items in the top menu. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener` you need to use this :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

For more info please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38195628/12768366) answer.

A quick overview you need to inflate different menu resource everytime you need to change your menu. Also you need to set `OnOptionsItemSelected` for the custom actions you need to perform.

You might also need to add this for fragment `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in your onCreate method.